# 403 error with SvelteKit form submissions behind ALB with TLS termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, svelte, csrf, sveltekit

I'm encountering an issue with form submissions in my SvelteKit application hosted behind an Application Load Balancer (ALB) in AWS with TLS termination. When submitting a form via HTTPS, the request fails with a "Cross-site POST form submissions are forbidden" 403 error.

However, form submissions work fine over HTTP or if I disable CSRF checks by setting csrf: `{ checkOrigin: false }`  in the SvelteKit config.

I've tried setting the `ORIGIN` environment variable to `http://www.example.com` during build time, but the issue persists. How can I resolve this problem and allow form submissions over HTTPS without disabling CSRF checks?

Im using `@sveltejs/adapter-node` for the adapter

Thank you!